# cloudkit disabled in capabilities after upgrade to xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded my MacOs and Xcode to 10.1 and the cloudkit does not show.

I have valid developer license. The cloudkit.framework is included in linked frameworks and libraries. The signing certificate is valid.
in Xcode ->General-> Signing
There are two options: 
My name
My name(Personal team) - 
I selected my name with Personal team option.
Is this correct?

Screen shot below
[image]

In my icloud account cloud dashboard shows my name with a role as Agent-Individual team and developer license. The container is listed.

I don't know why cloud kit does not show up in Xcode capabilities in my current project. I also created a new project no luck there either. Can someone advise?

Comment: it does not show in Xcode ->project -> capabilities. Also I have always selected the option with my name(personal team) and it worked. My question: which one one should I select and why and why not? By the way if I select the other option with just My name I get 2 ERRORS: ERROR 1: "failed to create provisioning profile and the app id cannot be registered to your development team, create a bundle with unique identifier"(probably because current app is registered to the one with personal team. ERROR 2: "provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate for iphone developer:..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Personal Team" is part of the free developer membership. Free developer members cannot use capabilities. If you do not have a paid developer membership, that's why you don't see any capabilities.

If you *do* have a paid developer membership, then you need to:

1. download a valid certificate for the paid developer membership
2. get your app out of the free developer membership and move it into the paid developer membership
3. download a new provisioning profile for this app that uses the paid developer certificate

(And stop using the Personal Team.)

It sounds to me like you do have a paid membership, and you seem to have done step 1, so you need to do steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you it worked, i renamed the bundle to unique name and regenerated profile with automatic signing. I am going to accept your answer. But one last question I wanted to configure push notifications to my new app on icloud dashboard. It asked me to generate a developer client certificate, which I did using keychain and saved it to disk. After this I thought the push notifications would say enabled but it still says configurable and displays the ssl certificate option. So how to ensure push notification is enabled now?

Comment: "But one last question I wanted to configure push notifications" That's leeching. One question per question please. Thank you.